# TFrameStand & C++Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

I use TFrameStand.
How to translate code from Delphi to C ++

```
procedure TMainForm.ShowButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  FFrameInfo: TFrameInfo<thelloworldframe>;
begin
  FFrameInfo := FrameStand1.New<thelloworldframe>(Layout1, 'bluestand');
  FFrameInfo.Show();
end;
```

I write

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    Framestand::TFrameInfo__1<tframe2*>* FFrameInfo;
    FFrameInfo = FrameStand1->New<tframe2*>(Layout1, "bluestand");
    FFrameInfo->Show();
}
```

And I get an error

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'Framestand::TFrameInfo__1 * __fastcall Framestand::TFrameStand::New(Fmx::Types::TFmxObject * const, System::UnicodeString)' referenced from UNIT1.OBJ

[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '__fastcall Framestand::TFrameInfo__1::Show(System::DelphiInterface *> >, System::DelphiInterface *> >, const bool)' referenced from UNIT1.OBJ
```

Comment: This is a linker error; it needs configuration to pull in the libraries.

Comment: I add 
#pragma link "FrameStand"

Comment: See [How to Handle Delphi Generics in C++](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/How_to_Handle_Delphi_Generics_in_C%2B%2B) in Embarcadero's documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article